# Apache redirecting example.com to ec2 public DNS

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2

**Setup**

Route 53 Domain `example.com` has `A` record to `id.cloudfront.net` and `AAAA` record to `random-id.cloudfront.net`.

Cloudfront has origin domain as EC2 public DNS `ec.xxxxxx.amazonaws.com` and alternate domain as `example.com`. Also, it has a AWS certificate for SSL/TLS (for now it accepts both HTTP & HTTPS requests)

EC2 is an Ubuntu-20.04 AMI with `apache2`, `php7.4` and `phpmyadmin`, all installed using `apt-get`.

**Issue** is whenever I put in `example.com/*` the site is automatically redirected to `ec.xxxxxx.amazonaws.com/*`.

Example:

- `example.com/phpmyadmin` gets redirected to `ec.xxxxxx.amazonaws.com/phpmyadmin/`.
- I tried to setup wordpress and `example.com` redirects to [http://ec2-xxxxxx.amazonaws.com/wp-admin/setup-config.php`](http://ec2-xxxxxx.amazonaws.com/wp-admin/setup-config.php%60)

These are the things I have tried.

- Added `ServerName example.com` in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`
- This command `sudo ufw allow in "Apache Full"`
- I do not have `.htaccess` in my `/var/www/html` folder.

Is it a Cloudfront or an Apache issue? This is my first rodeo with AWS and Apache and trying to learn how it works.

Solutions that seem out of scope:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/685654/apache-server-config-redirect-from-ip-to-domain-name-ec2
- Or anything that includes creating `.htaccess` at the root directory as I feel that would create an endless loop.

*I can provide more information, if required.*

Update:

- Removed A and AAAA record from route53. Doesn't work.
- Also, added `ServerName example.com` to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`
- Also, visiting `random-id.cloudfront.net` does the same redirection.
- However, visiting elastic-IP does not do any redirection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traced the issue to `HTTP_HOST` being the ec2 public DNS received by the server. So, if I visited `example.com/index.php` and the code were supposed to redirect to `example.com/index2.php` it would instead redirect to `ec.xxxxxx.amazonaws.com/index2.php` because `HTTP_HOST = ec.xxxxxx.amazonaws.com`.

Fixed by updating CloudFront Distribution's behavior to forward `Host` value.

So, if I visit `example.com` the host value would be `example.com`

And if I visit `id.cloudfront.net` then host value would be `id.cloudfront.net`.

[image]

https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.23

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your setup, probably you need CNAME instead of A record in Route53

Comment: This says otherwise, unless I misunderstood https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-cloudfront-distribution.html